# About the Default Account Halt

Tags: linux

In Linux server I have disabled the default account Halt. Even after disabling the account I can see the logs from the account stating that account activity has been detected for every one hour exactly.

Can anyone please explain me how get rid of the logs from the Halt account?

Comment: The log contains "user=halt password=x user_id=7 user_group_id=0 home=/sbin shell=/sbin/halt"